# How to prevent automatic initialization of ASP.Net in visual studio 2010?

Tags: asp.net, wpf, wcf, visual-studio

I am self-hosting a WCF Service Application. Its project has output type of Class Library. It is being hosted by a second WPF project with output type of Windows Application.

The WPF project is defined as the Startup project.

When I am debugging this, Visual Studio automatically starts an ASP.Net host for the WCF service. But this also binds the port so I can't debug this for transfer to another machine that does NOT have visual studio installed. The other machine will be using ServiceHost to attach the port and the debugger bombs when servicehost.Open() is hit.

How can I stop the automatic initialization of the ASP.Net host in visual studio 2010? Is there another way of doing this?

All help is *really* appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: There should be a tab in the properties page of the project marked WCF - there's an option there to enable/disable automatically starting the service host.

Comment: @Tim I hoped so...but I can't find it :(

Comment: @Tim Found it ...http://forums.asp.net/t/1439543.aspx. Thanks

Comment: Cool :)  You may want to post the answer below (referencing the link) so others may be able to use it as well.